React Native, Expo Router Tabs с кастомным поведением
я новичок в react native и столкнулся, видимо, с нетиповой задачей.
Задача: сделать навигацию так, чтобы она выглядела как компонент Tabs (кнопки внизу экрана), при этом, первая кнопка вызывала бы Drawer (выезжающее сбоку меню), а вторая - Bottom Sheet (выезжающая снизу модалка).
Главный вопрос: какой самый адекватный способ это реализовать?
Дополнительный вопрос: можно ли вообще комбинировать паттерны навигации, как указано в задаче? Кажется, что я запутался в концепции, но получается, что в _layout задаётся какой-то один способ навигации. И если в нём указан Tabs, то роуты выводятся в виде табов, а страница по нажатию на таб просто переключается; если указан Drawer - роуты выводятся в виде бокового меню. Переключившись табом на другую страницу, в её _layout можно указать, например, Stack и тогда страницы, вызванные отсюда, будут открыты в стеке "поверх" предыдущей. Но можно ли сделать чтобы по нажатию на другой таб, сразу вызывалась страница, как будто она была вызвана из стэка? К примеру. Или я пытаюсь пользоваться компонентом не по назначению и для моих задач нужно реализовывать что-то своё? Как бы вы это реализовали7
Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, уже неделю с этим бьюсь
